# Earliest use of "inversion" of arrow of time

Tags: time-travel, history-of

The recent movie Tenet is based around the idea of "inverting an object's entropy", to make it move backwards in time instead of forwards. A similar thing also happens in Greg Egan's Orthogonal trilogy, set in a fictional universe where

> if you travel fast enough you end up going backwards in time.

I'm wondering if there are earlier appearances of this idea in fiction, and if so, where it was first used.

To be clear, I'm not asking about time travel stories in general (not even ones where events are experienced in reverse order) - I'm interested specifically in stories where a character travels backwards in time at a rate of one second per second, interacting with other characters and/or the world around them in real time as they do so.

Comment: @user14111 thanks! I'm gonna say "The Man Who Lived Backwards" doesn't fit the bill, because I'm interested in stories that explore the physics of interacting time-lines, but "The Chronokinesis of Jonathan Hull" sounds like it fits

Comment: Seems to me that Superman could make the Earth revert to an earlier period by flying rapidly around it. In a 1960s comic book, I think.

Comment: **1938** Charles F. Hall, ["The Man Who Lived Backwards"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195076/what-story-does-c-s-lewis-acknowledge-in-the-preface-to-the-great-divorce); **1946** Anthony Boucher, ["The Chronokinesis of Jonathan Hull"](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v37n04_1946-06_cape1736#page/n117/mode/1up); **1949** M. C. Pease, ["Reversion"](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v44n04_1949-12_cape1736/page/n44/mode/1up); **1956** Charles L. Fontenay, ["Z"](https://archive.org/details/1956-06_IF_modified/page/n13/mode/1up).

Comment: I don't have time to compose a real answer to your question, so I'm throwing out these suggestions for anyone who wants to use them.

Comment: @Nathaniel   I have added another early example you might be slightly interested in.

Comment: @M.A.Golding thank you! (I don't like to accept answers too early, but I probably will after some time. I was hoping to find stories that explore the physics a bit more, but I realise a "what's the earliest" question probably isn't the best way to achieve that. Your answer is a good one!)

Answer (score 4):

An early fantasy character who lived life backwards from the future to the past is Merlin in *The Sword in the Stone* (1938) by T.H. White, which was revised and made part of *The Once and Future King* (1958).  As far as I remember Merlin lived backwards in time in both versions.

Of course, as far as I remember there was no explanation for Merlin living backwards and the readers would just assume magic as the cause.

Added 01-20-2021  An early television story with a similar plot, decades before *Tenet* was the *Star trek: The Animated Series*  (TAS) episode "The Counter-Clock Incident", in which the *Enterprise* and its crew enter an alternate universe where time goes backwards and they start getting younger.

I thought that the fictional physics was a bit illogical, but it was a dramactic production that did more or less explore the physics of backwards time decades before *Tenet*, although after the examples of written storeis that User 14111 suggested.

Comment: _where time goes backwards and they start getting younger_ These things never make sense. They would not notice any difference, as their memories are not of the future. It would be like getting older inside a body that gets younger.